# ibm-mobilefirst: How to get adapter.xml connectivity.connectionPolicy object in JS adapter

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using MFP8 and i want to log the current *connectionPolicy* object, defined in the adapter.xml file, from inside the JS adapter.
I can't find in the ufficial documentation anything that suits my needs.
***Let's assume*** a method named ***MFP.getXmlAdapterConfig(parms)*** exists, that allowes me to get those data...

**adapter.xml**:

```
<connectivity>
    <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <domain>mydomain.com</domain>
        <port>80</port>
[ . . .]
```

**adapter.js**

```
var cp = MFP.getXmlAdapterConfig("connectivity").connectionPolicy;
```

what i need to achieve is the construction of the current environment path:

```
var path = cp.protocol + "://" + cp.domain + ":" + cp.port + "/";
//path = http://mydomain:80/
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need these values within the adapter code?
MFP runtime will construct the path to the backend under the covers. All you need to do is use the MFP.Server.invokeHttp() API.

Comment: logging purposes: i need to log request, response and endpoint.

Comment: I need it because obviously depending on the configuration pushed on the server (at its turn depending by the invironment it needs to point to) the endpoints will be different. The logs must have the same form, though.
Unfortunately using an apposite property is not contemplated.